# What does every part of the "mount -t cifs -o username=root //ipadress/map/mnt/map" command mean?

Tags: command-line, mount

The command:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=root //ipadress/map/mnt/map
```

So I mean like what does "mount" mean? What does "-t" mean? Etc.

Comment: As a starting point, have you tried reading the documentation for the `mount` command, with `man mount`?

Comment: Hi there, I am currently not using my Linux device But I need this for A test that I have tomorrow

Comment: You're asking us to understand it for you?

Comment: No I want you Guys to tell me What The commands are and What they mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are wondering what a command means, the first step is to run `man command` (where "command" is the command in question, so `man mount` in this case). That will bring up the command's manual which usually includes a short description of what it does and also an explanation of the various options. Admittedly, the `man` pages are not always very clear to new users, but they're always a good start.

Now, let's have a look at `man mount`. The first lines are:

```
NAME
       mount - mount a filesystem
```

So `mount` is the command you use to [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) a filesystem. Mounting a file system simply means attaching it to a directory. So that when you `cd` into that directory, you see the contents of the filesystem. The most common scenario is where the filesystem is a hard drive or a hard drive partition. So, on your Linux box, your main hard drive partition is mounted on the root (`/`) directory. On a Windows machine, it is mounted at `C:\`. Same basic idea.

Now, the things that start with `-` are command line options, also known as "switches" or "flags". The `-t` specifies the filesystem type:

```
   -t, --types fstype
          The argument following the -t is used to indicate the filesystem
          type.  The filesystem types which are currently supported depend
          on the running  kernel.   See  /proc/filesystems  and  /lib/mod‐
          ules/$(uname  -r)/kernel/fs  for a complete list of the filesys‐
          tems.  The most common are ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs,  btrfs,  vfat,
          sysfs, proc, nfs and cifs.
```

In this case, you are mounting a remote directory using CIFS, the Common Internet File System. This is basically a protocol for file sharing, essentially. It's an easy and portable way of mounting a remote directory onto your local machine.

The `-o` is how you set the various possible options for mounting. Here, you are only setting one option: the username of the user to whom the files in the mounted filesystem will belong. Specifically, you will be mounting as root so everything on that filesystem will appear to belong to the root user.

The final argument is what you are mounting. The general format of the mount command is:

```
mount [OPTIONS] -t FILESYSTEM TARGET MOUNTPOINT
```

The `TARGET` is what you are attempting to mount. In your case, you seem to want to mount the directory `/map/mnt/map` which is found on the machine with the IP address `ip`. If you were to actually run the command to, for example, mount something from the machine on your local network with the IP of `192,168.1.10`, you would run:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=root //192.168.1.10/map/mnt/map TARGET
```

However, the command is incomplete. You also need a target, the directory where this will be mounted. The mountpoint. This can be any directory on your local machine, preferably an empty one<sup>1</sup>. so, to mount the remote directory `/map/mnt/map` from the server `192.168.1.10` onto your local directory `/mnt/myshare` (create the directory first with `sudo mkdir /mnt/myshare`), you would run:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=root //ipadress/map/mnt/map /mnt/myshare
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>If you choose a non-empty directory, any files in it will be masked by the contents of the mounted filesystem. Unmounting will bring them back, but it can be a cause for some consternation, so choose an empty directory for this.</sub>